# How to get contentEditable element's updated value in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, forms, html-table

```js
var myApp = angular.module("problemApp", []);
 
   myApp.controller("RESTCall", function ($scope, $compile, $element, $timeout) {
  $scope.username = 'Adan';
  console.log($scope.username)
  $scope.printValue = function(data) {
     $timeout(function () { 
        $scope.$apply(function(){
           console.log(data);
        });
     });      
  }
});
```

```css
table td, th{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="problemApp">
<div  ng-controller="RESTCall">
  <form name="covertToProForm" id=
"table-print">
  <table id="confirm">
    <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <td contentEditable ng-keyup="printValue(username)" ng-model="username">{{username}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <td>Smith</td>
    </tr>
</table>
  </form>
</div>
  
</div>
```

I have the above table which has a `td`, that has `contentEditable` attribute. On editing `td`'s value, I want to print its value in console. Any help would be appreciated!

Edited snippet with the given answer. It's not working.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#custom-control-example

Answer (score 0):

Please disregard my previous answer. The whole thing is we need to wrap `contenteditable` in a custom directive because `contenteditable` directive does not not work directly with angular's `ng-model` just because it re-render the dom element on every change, resulting in loosing the recent `ng-model` change.

here's a new `wrapper` around `contenteditable`

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('contenteditable', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: 'ngModel',
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.username = 'Adan';
      $scope.printValue = function() {
        console.log($scope.username);
      }
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, myController) {

      element.on('keyup', function() {
        scope.$apply(updateViewModel);
      });

      function updateViewModel() {
        var htmlValue = element.text()
        myController.$setViewValue(htmlValue);
        scope.printValue();
      }
      myController.$render = updateHtml

      function updateHtml() {
        var viewModelValue = myController.$viewValue
        element.text(viewModelValue);

      }
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.7" data-semver="1.2.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.7/angular.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h2>{{username}}</h2>
      <form>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <td contenteditable ng-model="username">{{username}}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <td>Smith</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Edited snippet with the given answer. It's not working.

Comment: sure, let me see

Comment: It worked for angular1.X but, problems arising for angular 2.0